# Finding SHA1 in git for file version containing a given line containing a given string

Tags: git

I'm trying to track down a memory leak reported to me by a tester using valgrind, which reports memory leaks with a traceback for when it was allocated. Unfortunately, the file they're reporting it on has changed significantly since they tested. I'm trying to find out what version they tested with. To do this, I'd like to look up when the file had a given function call at a given line number (from the valgrind report), on a linux / bash system, using git.

In other words, the valgrind report had something like this in the traceback:

```
   function1 (file1.c:line1)
   function2 (file2.c:line2)
```

Assuming the line numbers are correct (ie: the functions aren't wrapped in macros or inlines that might confuse valgrind), I'm looking for the version of file2.c, where line2 contained string "function1".

My attempt was first using "git log --follow file2.c | grep ^commit". As a quick test, I collected that output:

```
commit f267c7671a8af8a4c97b5c4938bab3a7099d50ea
commit 3f45349afc39b5c3ed6a6517ee4a2008d21f9047
commit 09e489d88ecc9e0adee326d68f18834753ddbcdd
commit 14ae0ab236bea453a9e2af81b507fe8243813b34
commit e1c1b28671a5c957c77ce54a45ce7e1694a64592
commit 7a45c4761c7f0d2263934d254c50052941d0c9e7
commit db9e61c3253a8c6966ecf334ff9c394e17966188
...about a hundred SHA1 labels...
```

into an editor, and search/replaced each line with:

```
show f267c7671a8af8a4c97b5c4938bab3a7099d50ea:file2 | sed -n(line2)p
show 3f45349afc39b5c3ed6a6517ee4a2008d21f9047:file2 | sed -n(line2)p
show 09e489d88ecc9e0adee326d68f18834753ddbcdd:file2 | sed -n(line2)p
show 14ae0ab236bea453a9e2af81b507fe8243813b34:file2 | sed -n(line2)p
show e1c1b28671a5c957c77ce54a45ce7e1694a64592:file2 | sed -n(line2)p
show 7a45c4761c7f0d2263934d254c50052941d0c9e7:file2 | sed -n(line2)p
show db9e61c3253a8c6966ecf334ff9c394e17966188:file2 | sed -n(line2)p
...
```

But I didn't find a match. I did some more checking, and did find one match that was "off-by-one" line number (I've found valgrind line numbers are normally accurate on our system, but perhaps it could be off-by-one).

So my first question is, will the "git log" really show me all the versions of that file? Assuming no one's re-written history in the repository. I'm wondering if I've missed a version with this approach.

My second question is, is there a good way to automate this? Ideally, I'm thinking of a script that would take a file name and line range (lineA to lineC), and report for each version:

```
(shaX) lineA : contentsXA
(shaX) lineB : contentsXB
(shaX) lineC : contentsXC
(shaY) lineA : contentsYA
(shaY) lineB : contentsYB
(shaY) lineC : contentsYC
(shaZ) lineA : contentsZA
(shaZ) lineB : contenstZB
(shaZ) lineC : contentsZC
```

I could grep the output of that for the string I'm looking for, and I'd see the SHA of the version(s) that contained that string. Or is there a better way to approach this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the git repository and picking `check_sha1_signature` from `sha1_file.c` as a concrete example, you can see the lines where that function was defined with

```
git log --format=format:%H -- sha1_file.c | \
  xargs -I SHA1 env GIT_PAGER=cat \
  git grep --word-regexp --line-num check_sha1_signature SHA1 -- sha1_file.c
```

Because the name of the source file is hardcoded in the `git grep` command, this will not follow renames.

Comment: I haven't used "--format=format:%H", that's helpful. Unfortunately, git reported:

    `error: unknown open 'line-num'`

Is that from a newer version of git? I'm using 1.7.3.4 on Suse linux.

Comment: I see it's "-n" instead of "--line-num" in my version of git. Printing out all the matching lines, and showing the line number is probably even better than what I was trying to do (print them only if they match). Thanks!